# Typescript: 'gridTemplateColumns' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.ts(2783)

Tags: typescript

I upgraded my typescript version from 4.0.5 to 4.9.5 in my react project.

In the following code (styled components):

```
export const __offerBlock: IStyles = (props: any) => ({
  gridTemplateColumns: "18% auto",
  ...(props.isMobile
    ? {
        margin: "0 15px",
        gridTemplateColumns: "10% auto"
      }
    : {
        width: "98%"
      })
});
```

I'm getting this error:

```
'gridTemplateColumns' is specified more than once, so this usage will be overwritten.ts(2783)
__fileNameStyles.ts(158, 3): This spread always overwrites this property.
```

[image]

How do I allow typescript to allow overwrite using spread?
Also, why is the error coming when I'm conditionally adding the "gridTemplateColumns" property.

This error only started after bumping up the ts version.

Comment: You could suppress the warning, but I'd suggest just simplifying the function by moving `gridTemplateColumns` from the top into the second branch. No point in specifying it at the top if you're just going to overwrite it in half of the branches, and it has the benefit of fixing the error. And there's no need for the spread at all, you're just copying objects you just created and aren't going to reuse. https://tsplay.dev/WkD79w

Comment: Makes sense, however I've just simplified by cutting out the lines for the question. In my project code there are too many nesting and too many spreads,. It did not complain before but suddenly after version change it is showing this error. I guess I'll just supress it.

Comment: If you post the complex version (within reason), we can probably help you rewrite it to avoid the repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move the outer `gridTemplateColumns` into the else clause of the ternary:

```js
export const __offerBlock: IStyles = (props: any) => ({
  ...(props.isMobile
    ? {
        margin: "0 15px",
        gridTemplateColumns: "10% auto"
      }
    : {
        width: "98%",
        gridTemplateColumns: "18% auto"
      })
});
```

However, while I'm at it, might I suggest that you change this even further? What you are basically doing here is returning one of two different literal objects, so you can just write your function like that instead:

```js
export const __offerBlock: IStyles = (props: any) => {
  if (props.isMobile) {
    return {
      margin: "0 15px",
      gridTemplateColumns: "10% auto"
    }
  } else {
    return {
      width: "98%",
      gridTemplateColumns: "18% auto"
    }
  }
}
```